# Set time in email for password recovery

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I wrote a code for recovery of password. In which, If any existing user enter his email in required field then a link for password recovery send on his email and then if he click on received link then he will go on password recovery page. It is working perfectly.

**But I need time link. Means If I set 60 seconds for password recovery link on email then within 60 sec. user can recover password otherwise link will be fail.** I have no idea how to do? Please give me hints.

My fields in table are: **name, email, mobile, password, passcode**

**update.php (For insert email to send recovery email link)**

```
  <?php
 include("connection.php");
 extract($_POST);
if(isset($email)==true)
 {
 $query=mysql_query("select * from account where email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());    
 $result=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($result==1)
{
$salt = "498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13";
    $restkey = hash('sha512', $salt.$email);

mysql_query("update account SET passcode='$restkey' where email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());

$to="$email";
$subject="Password Reset";
    $pwrurl = "demo.cstechnology.net/updatepass.php?restkey=".$restkey;
$message="To reset your password, please click the link below. If you cannot click it, please paste it into your web browser's address bar.\n\n" . $pwrurl . "\n\nThanks,\nThe Administration";
    $header="FROM:vinubangs@gmail.com";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);    

  }
  else
  {
 echo "Invalid Email";  

 }
 }

 ?>
 <form action="" method="post">
 <table>
 <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="email" required name="email" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
  </form>
```

**updatepass.php (After click on recovery email link on email. Password will be update)**

```
  <?php
  session_start();
   include("connection.php");
   extract($_REQUEST);
   extract($_POST);

  if(isset($submit)==true)
   {
  $query=mysql_query("update account SET password='$password' where passcode='$restkey'") or die(mysql_error());
  echo"Password Updated Successfully";
  }



  if(isset($restkey)==true)
  {

  echo"<form action='' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type='password' required name='password' /></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' /></td></tr>
 </form>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `$salt = "498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13";` A salt should be unique for each stored credential ([OWASP: Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Use_a_cryptographically_strong_credential-specific_salt))

Comment: $salt is unique and I added it with $email.

Comment: I wouldn't use this code in a live environment; it's not as safe as you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add extra `timestamp` column in table, so when user clicks on password recovery save here a time.

```
ALTER TABLE account ADD timestamp INT
```

Then when user calls updatepass.php you need to compare current time with the timestamp saved in table.

update.php

```
$resettimestamp=time();
$query=mysql_query("update account set timestamp=$resettimestamp where email='$email'");
```

updatepass.php

```
$query=mysql_query("select timestamp from account where email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());    
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$timestamp=$row[0];
$currtime=time();
$timewindow=60; // 60 seconds
if ($currtime-$timestamp<=$timewindow) {
 //your logic to reset password
 }
else {
 //Tell the user that he is too slow )
}
```

Also please note, that **mysql** is no more supported in PHP 7.0, so use **mysqli** instead if possible

Comment: Thank you for reply. It can be work. I will try sure.

Comment: Please mark question as answered, I'll update it with code samples in couple of minutes

Comment: what will be the type of field?

Comment: INT will be enough